# Lucas–Kanade method vs Kanade–Lucas–Tomasi feature tracker

Tags: computer-vision

Can anyone explain the relationship between these two?

I know that LK method is used to find the optical flow of an image vs KLT tracker which detects features of an image.  Is there any relationship between the two?

Is KLT tracker algorithm used in the LK method to find the optical flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The KLT method is composed of two step:

1. a so called GoodFeaturesToTrack (GFT) feature detection step. That detects features at positions in your image with edge-like or texture rich structures.
2. the feature tracking based on the Lucas-Kanade (LK) method for these detected feature points.

LK methode is an optical flow-based methode that computes the motion vectors at predefined positions in an image sequence.

So KLT contains GFT + LK. The **idea behind the KLT** is that the LK accuracy is in theory better at edge-like locations in the image sequence. So that with the GFT. It is **more likely to obtain accurate feature tracks**. And you can reduce the number of features to track in advance to **reduce the processing power.**

Comment: Ah I see, so LK is used inside KLT

Comment: you mean corner-like locations in the image, not edge-like. May seem trivial difference, but it really isnt

Comment: Yes you are right. To be more precisse feature with bi-directional gradients. So that the gradient matrix can be inverted.

Comment: @Lun Zhang, yeah LK is used inside KLT. There is huge confusion about this topic, keeps coming back questions with wrong answers saying that LK is a sparse flow method, which it is not! KLT is sparse. Most likely, the reason so many get the wrong idea is beacuase KLT sounds similar to LK, and because the documentation of Opencv is off on this topic. They call the demo of KLT for LKdemo.cpp, for starters

Answer (score 3):

The Lucas-Kanade (LK) method is an image registration method, originally introduced with applications in stereovision. This is used in tracking, optical flow and other similar applications.

The KLT has three important aspects:

1) It uses an interest point/ feature detector, such as Harris Corner Detector, to detect good features to track. You can also see examples with other detectors such as FAST.

2) The tracking is done using LK method. This method originally proceeded by assuming a translation between the frames. The translation parameters were obtained by minimizing an error function. In the case of tracking, a feature in a particular frame is compared to the same feature in the previous frame.

3) The tracking quality of a feature may vary over time. This is checked using a dissimilarity function which assumes an affine transformation between frames. In this case, a feature in a particular frame is compared to the same feature in the first frame, not necessarily the previous frame.

Depending on the application, there might be variations in the KLT implementation. It may use a different feature detector or may use affine model for tracking. Also, there are more modern variants of Lucas-Kanade algorithm such as Inverse Compositional Algorithm.

Here are a few resources which will help you understand the KLT algorithm (or Inverse Compositional Algorithm):

[1] Bruce D. Lucas and Takeo Kanade. [An Iterative Image Registration Technique with an Application to Stereo Vision.](https://cecas.clemson.edu/~stb/klt/lucas_bruce_d_1981_1.pdf) International Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence, pages 674-679, 1981.

[2] Carlo Tomasi and Takeo Kanade. [Detection and Tracking of Point Features.](https://cecas.clemson.edu/~stb/klt/tomasi-kanade-techreport-1991.pdf) Carnegie Mellon University Technical Report CMU-CS-91-132, April 1991.

[3] Jianbo Shi and Carlo Tomasi. [Good Features to Track](https://cecas.clemson.edu/~stb/klt/shi-tomasi-good-features-cvpr1994.pdf). IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, pages 593-600, 1994.

[4] Stan Birchfield. [Derivation of Kanade-Lucas-Tomasi Tracking Equation.](https://cecas.clemson.edu/~stb/klt/birchfield-klt-derivation.pdf) Unpublished, January 1997.

[5] [KLT: An Implementation of the Kanade-Lucas-Tomasi Feature Tracker](https://cecas.clemson.edu/~stb/klt/)

[6] [Inverse Compositional Method](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV0910/zhao.pdf)

[7] [Lucas-Kanade 20 Years On: A Unifying Framework](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Iain_Matthews2/publication/248602429_Lucas-Kanade_20_Years_On_A_Unifying_Framework_Part_1_The_Quantity_Approximated_the_Warp_Update_Rule_and_the_Gradient_Descent_Approximation/links/0046352ab4010b9de9000000.pdf)

The Optical Flow started out with a brightness constancy assumption. The idea was to find out two translation parameters using this assumption. However, since there are two unknowns an additional constraint was required. This was obtained with the smoothness assumption. However, this assumption can be avoided by considering a small 3 x 3 window around the point whose displacement is to be found out. This generates a system of 9 equations using brightness constancy assumption alone. This system is solved using LK method.

Here are a few resources associated with Optical Flow:

[1] [Determining optical flow](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/6337/%EE%80%80AIM%EE%80%81-572.pdf?sequence=2).

[2] [Pyramidal implementation of the affine lucas kanade feature tracker description of the algorithm.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/aa97/2b40c0f8e20b07e02d1fd320bc7ebadfdfc7.pdf)

[3] [Two-frame motion estimation based on polynomial expansion](https://www.ida.liu.se/ext/WITAS-ev/Computer_Vision_Technologies/Papers/scia03_farneback.pdf).

Both KLT and Optical Flow use LK method. KLT relies on a feature detector to detect good features and is sparse. Optical Flow may be either sparse or dense. The sparse versions rely on some kind of feature detector, just like KLT. Even the dense versions use some sampling to reduce computation cost. However, optical flow does not have any steps which uses dissimilarity to check if a feature is worth tracking over time. Also, the original concept of KLT was developed along with/ or as an extension of LK method. The Optical Flow, on the other hand, initially relied on Calculus of Variation to find a solution after applying two constraints and started as a different idea/ method.

The equations for parameter update for both KLT and Optical Flow (using Lucas Kande method) are pretty much the same. The sparse optical flow implementation in OpenCV is based on the second paper listed under the resources for Optical Flow. This paper uses Affine transformation for tracking. The original KLT proposes translation model for tracking and affine model to check the quality of features.